# Middleware req.params not pulling the right value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
// set a cookie to requested locale
var setLanguage = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.locale === undefined) {
        req.params.locale = 'pt';
        res.cookie('locale', 'pt');
    } else {
        req.params.locale = req.params.locale;
        res.cookie('locale', req.params.locale);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        next();
    }, 2000);
};

app.get('/:locale?', setLanguage, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.cookies.locale);
  res.render('index');
});
```

I made this custom middleware to load the language depending on the req.params.locale, the renderization is ok, but there is a problem with this code and i don't know exactly what is.

When i try to access for example: /, will work the pt, because is the default.. but when i try to access /en after that, the pt will render, but if i try to access the english after that, will work normally.

I don't know why is that, someone knows????

UPDATE -

I am using morgan to debug and i put a console.log here:

```
app.get('/:locale?', setLanguage, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.cookies.locale);
  res.render('index');
});
```

When i try access the /:

```
pt
GET / 304 28.069 ms - -
```

After that, if i try access /en:

```
GET / 200 21.543 ms - 153
pt
GET /en 304 8.730 ms - -
pt
GET /en 200 2.612 ms - 153
```

Now, i am going back to /pt:

```
GET /en 200 2.612 ms - 153
en
GET /pt 200 3.984 ms - 159
en
GET /pt 200 2.498 ms - 159
```

Anyone knows what is causing that?

UPDATE --

I am using this [module](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node).

And the code to make it work is:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

// set a cookie to requested locale
app.get('/:locale', function (req, res) {
  res.cookie('locale', req.params.locale);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

This is an stupid way of change the language, because i am going to repeat my self in every route that receives a locale parameter, so i am trying to use middleware:

Middleware:

```
function setLanguage (req, res, next) {
   req.params.locale = req.params.locale || 'pt';
   res.cookie('locale', req.params.locale);
   next();
}
```

Them i can call this middleware in every route that i want, for example:

```
app.get('/:locale?', setLanguage......
app.get('/other/:locale?', setLanguage......
app.get('/something/locale?', setLanguage......
```

But this is making the language not change, i need reload the page twices... i don't know how exactly solve this....

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '?' in the url where you define the REST API in the node.js code and it will work fine:

```
app.get('/:locale', setLanguage, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.cookies.locale);
  res.render('index');
});
```

As well as the way you checking for undefined is incorrect you can simply do it like this:

```
if (req.params.locale) {
      //Rest of your code
}
```

UPDATE (try this):

```
// set a cookie to requested locale
var setLanguage = function(req, res) {
    var locale = req.params.locale || 'pt';
        res.cookie('locale', locale);
    }
    res.render('index');
};

app.get('/:locale', setLanguage});
```

Comment: still the same problem, if i try to change the language, the first try will not work, but if i reload the page, will work.. =/

Comment: @DRX: added an update section where I modified your code and made it simpler. Do try this one.

Comment: same behaviour @V31, you can look here -> https://test-celicoo1-4.c9.io/ the languages are pt, en and fr.. if i try to change, the first time will not work, but if reloaded will.. i don't know why...

Comment: i did https://test-celicoo1-4.c9.io/fr and the response cookie has the locale as fr though. So it kind of worked

Comment: thats because i am using the crap code who comes with the module, i am going to update my answer, check out..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70766/discussion-between-v31-and-drx).